# JDBC ODBC Driver Support for Excel on Linux

Tags: linux, excel, jdbc

I'm looking for help in finding some workaround so that we can:

1. use an Excel driver (preferably some kind of ODBC-JDBC bridge), and
2. use SQL queries with the driver.

Do such facilities exist?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SQLSheet](http://code.google.com/p/sqlsheet/) with some success in the past. It supports basic `CREATE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.